# Autocomplete in Ubuntu Windows 10 subsystem adds an additional "/"

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I use auto completion for file names in the Windows 10 Ubuntu bash, it always adds the "/" directory symbol, and then says "Not a directory". So I always have to backspace and erase that - I can't just, say,  vim + f + tab to open foo in vim.

Any idea on how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to `~/.inputrc`

```
set mark-directories Off
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, though I had to create the file ~/.inputrc. However, my linux as opposed to the ubuntu windows 10 subsystem knows the difference between folders and files.